# Symfony 2 production env constant errors

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, production

I developed my Symfony 2.8 project locally on dev enviroment.
Than i needed to upload it to a server and run it on production.
I did all the steps:
1. Checked it out with git on the server
2. Ran composer install
3. Cleared cache, doctrine cache, installed the assets
4. Configured my database

Saying this ... I`m still getting problems like:

- Internel server errors like

  > No route found for "GET ..

And for some reason it makes requests from time to time to app_dev.php - my ht access clearly states that directory index is app.php and etc

- I get double template rendering - the same view is loaded two times - two menu section ... two content section

I am really frustrated, cause i`ve tried everything i know. Could someone help me, i`ll provide additional info if needed.
I need any suggestions, ideas and etc that could help me.

My .htaccess file  - http://pastebin.com/4XHetMPV

Comment: can you show us your htaccess file and your index.php file

Comment: The front controller is app.php . I developed it on windows and the frontcontroller is in web/app.php . Now i moved it to a linux hosting and all of the files are in public_html directory. Is this the wrong way ?

Comment: I think it's write can you check the app.php file if it has this $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);

Comment: Yes it has it. This is the app.php - http://pastebin.com/Yg31JzHY
I think i may have missed something major ... i don`t know. I checked the web/check.php and everything ...

Comment: check if you are loading all your routes with  php app/console router:debug

Comment: Yes, i load them all. The problem is on one request ... i get an error - on other request of the same url - all is fine. I guess there is some problem with the cache but can`t find it ...

Comment: You could also edit the app_dev.php file by uncommenting the localhost check. After that you will be able to get further error details and even the symfony toolbar by accessing app_dev.php instead. Just for debugging - restore the app_dev.php after solving your problems.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to remove your cache manually and clean your logs :
`rm -rf app/cache/* && rm app/logs/prod.log`

Then, try to browse a route of your application.
If you still have an error, open your log using `cat app/logs/prod.log` and find the last error.

If it's a php error caused by a vendor, remove your `/vendor` directory and run `composer update`

If you are not able to fix your problem, add to your question the error log and  code of the method called by your route that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As chalasr said, cleaning prod cache manually works after the app.php setup.

I think a command like :

`php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

should work too.